# Which type to store an Array of MongoDB ObjectIds?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, typescript, mongoose-populate

I want to save an Array of ObjectIds which I get via an REST interface via mongoose to a mongodb. I constantly run into the problem that I **get a cast error when I save the objectsIds from the REST interface to the DB**. The serverside code is written in typescript.

The schema is:

```
var WaSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ownerId: { type: 'String', required: true },
    options: { type: 'String', required: false },
    launch:  [{ type : 'ObjectId', required: true }],
});
```

From the REST interface I get for "lanch" an Array of strings: `launch:  Array<string>`

Here is how I currently do the save:

```
WaModel.findOneAndUpdate(query, {
            ownerId: userId,
            options: wa.options,
            launch: wa.launch
        },
        { upsert: true },
        (err, doc) => {
            if (err) throw err
            else return 'successfully saved/updated';
        })
```

1. How must the ObjectId in the REST interface needs to look like to be correctly casted? Is it just a sting like '575e52790c0fc76a11e381d0' or does it need a prefix like ObjectId("575e52790c0fc76a11e381d0")?
2. How would the Array look like at the end? This depends a liitle on the answer of #1
3. I saw the populate function, can this be of help here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) If you are using mongoose then no need to add prefix ObjectId. You can save as an array of reference Ids.

```
var insertData = {
            ownerId: userId,
            options: wa.options,
            launch:  [ '56cea954d82cd11004ee67b5','56ceaa00d82cd11004ee67bc' ]
           }
```

2) At the end your array will look like this.

```
"launch" : [ 
        ObjectId("56cea954d82cd11004ee67b5"), 
        ObjectId("56ceaa00d82cd11004ee67bc")            
    ],
```

3) And Yes, populate function will be helpful here. It will populate whole array. After populate it will look like

```
"launch" : [ 
             { _id: '56cea954d82cd11004ee67b5',
               .... other fields
             },
             { _id: '56ceaa00d82cd11004ee67bc',
              .... other fields
             },
          ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say store the object ids in array with datatype `ObjectId`. So to do that you should convert the id in string format that is `'575e52790c0fc76a11e381d0'` into type `ObjectId`.

Use the following to convert it:

Consider the id is of `a user (userId)`

```
var stringUserId = '575e52790c0fc76a11e381d0';
var ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
var userId = ObjectId(stringUserId); //This should assign a value of datatype ObjectId to userId
```